# How do I change the position of viewPager from Main Activity, when the viewPager is in the main fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an `Activity` that is holding a main `Fragment` which then contains a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`. I have implemented a `NavigationDrawer` i my `MainActivity` and want to change the `viewPager.setCurrentItem` when the user clicks an Item in the `NavigationDrawer`.

How can I pass the data from the `NavigationDrawer` in my `MainActivity`, to the `ViewPager` which is in my `Fragment`?

**Main Activity:**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        //TODO: handle the item clicks in navDrawer
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                // Here I want to call viewPager.setCurrentItem(0), but I cannot call this from here. 
                Toast.makeText(NITrafficActivity.this, "Home!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cctv:
                Toast.makeText(NITrafficActivity.this, "CCTV Cameras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_future_roadworks:
                Toast.makeText(NITrafficActivity.this, "Future Roadworks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_journey_times:
                Toast.makeText(NITrafficActivity.this, "Journey Times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_speed_cameras:
                Toast.makeText(NITrafficActivity.this, "Speed Cameras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        return true;
    }
```

**Main Fragment:**

```
public class TrafficTabsFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackPressedHandler {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_traffic_tabs, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final List<Pair<String, Fragment>> tabs = CollectionsKt.arrayListOf(
                new Pair<String, Fragment>(getString(R.string.roadworks, 0), RoadworksFeedFragment.newInstance()),
                new Pair<String, Fragment>(getString(R.string.incidents, 0), IncidentsFeedFragment.newInstance())
        );

        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.main_tab_layout);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new TrafficTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabs));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        monitorFilterCount(viewModel.roadworksFilterCount, 0, R.string.roadworks);
        monitorFilterCount(viewModel.incidentsFilterCount, 1, R.string.incidents);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass position to fragment from its reference.
Inside your TrafficTabsFragment,add this method.

```
public void changeItem(int position){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,true);
}
```

Inside onNavigationItemSelected callback,call changeItem method passing position argument.

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    //TODO: handle the item clicks in navDrawer
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            //call it here
            trafficTabFragment.changeItem(0);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_cctv:
            trafficTabFragment.changeItem(1);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_future_roadworks:
            trafficTabFragment.changeItem(2);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_journey_times:
            trafficTabFragment.changeItem(3);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_speed_cameras:
            trafficTabFragment.changeItem(4);
            break;
    }
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
```